# ввод и вывод на форме

Tags: java, label, jtextfield

в окне формы надо ввести число

и распечатать его факториал

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  JTextField text = new JTextField(2);
  JLabel label;
  public  Main(){
    super("факториал");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Отображение введенного текста
        new JLabel(calcFactorial((int)text.getText()));
      }
    });
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(label);
    setContentPane(panel);
    setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private int calcFactorial(int n){
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
      res *= i;
    }
    return res;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

поле ввода сделал

а как вывести не пойму

подумал может в лейбел

но что-то не так получается

Comment: 1. Проинициализируйте label, перед тем, как делать panel.add(label); 2. вместо new JLabel... попробуйте label.setText()

Comment: сделал так: label.setText(": "+calcFactorial(Integer.parseInt(text.getText()))); - получилось. спс